# php, retain variables through multiple form submits

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to build a list of names submitted in a form, but my variable is reset every time the form gets submitted. I read some things that made it seem like hidden variables would help, but it's not working. Any ideas welcome. I'm expecting users to enter one name at a time. I'd like to display them all each time the form is submitted.  Sorry to include so much code, any comments welcome.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$gname = "";

$counter = isset($_POST['counter']) ? $_POST['counter'] : 0;
$guestlist = isset($_POST['guestlist']) ? $_POST['guestlist'] : "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    $counter++;
if( isset($_POST["paidflag"]) && !empty($_POST["paidflag"]) )
  $paidflag = test_input($_POST["paidflag"]);
else
  $paidflagErr = "Please select either Paid or Guest Pass";
if (empty($_POST["gname"])) {
  $gnameErr = "<b>Error: Enter a guest name before hitting 'Submit.'</b><br>";
}
else
 ....
}

<br><br>
 Enter guest name and click the button for Paid or Guest Pass.
<form id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="paidflag" value="Paid"> <b>Paid </b>
<input type="radio" name="paidflag" value="Guest Pass"> <b>Guest Pass</b>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $paidflagErr;?></span>
<br> <br>
 <b> Name:</b>  <input type="text" name="gname">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $gnameErr;?></span>
<br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type = "hidden" name = "counter" value = "<?php print $counter; ?>"; />
  <input type = "hidden" name = "guestlist" value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($guestlist); ?>"; />
</form>


<?php

if( (!$gnameErr) && ( $paidflag == "Paid" || $paidflag == "Guest Pass")) {

 $vc++;
 if($counter>0) {

 $gl2 = $gname . ", " . $paidflag . "<br>";
 $guestlist .= $gl2;

 echo "<br>Guest checked in today: <br>" .  $guestlist;
```

Ok, I'm adding more to this after looking at the help from yesterday. Thanks Dexter0015!
I ended up making things work with Session. I still don't understand why it won't work with a hidden variable, but I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

One issue with sessions is that I was preserving the data longer than I wanted it. I need to build an array for a given user and once they close the window I want the array to be cleared. Here's the work around I came up with:

```
$counter = (!empty($_POST['counter'])) ? $_POST['counter'] : 0;
//purge list the first time through
$guest_list = ($counter==0) ? "" : $_SESSION['guest_list'];
```

I defined a hidden counter variable to see how many times the form was completed. If $counter is 0 I want to clear the array.  This seems to work fine.

I had problems using the suggested approach for the array.
These lines produced the following error:
    $guests_list[] = $new_guest;
    $_SESSION['guests_list'] = $guests_list;

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use [] for reading in ...

But this isn't a big problem, b/c I don't mind using a string and building the html array in php. I did that as:
    $new_guest = '

' . $gname . ', ' . $paidflag . '

';
    $guest_list .= $new_guest;

I also still have a basic question about flow and processing.  When I set up a form to be processed by php, it looks like the whole php code runs every time the form is submitted. Is there a way to set up some initialization section that is only run the first time the page is set up?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Create a session, or create hidden input values, on $_POST retain that value and assign it to a hidden value in the form on the next "page"

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I follow. I thought that's what I was doing with this:   <input type = "hidden" name = "guestlist" value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($guestlist); ?>"; />     But $guestlist is reset everytime the form is submitted.  The data from the previous submit is not retained.

Comment: Can you post the actual state of your complete code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to store your variable, and as you want to store several names in it, use an array rather than a string.

Here is how I would organize the code:

```
<?php
// 1 - Init session: needs to be first thing in your code
session_start();

// Init variable from session or null if doesn't exist
$guests_list = (!empty($_SESSION['guest_list']))? $_SESSION['guest_list'] : array();
$counter = (!empty($_POST['counter']))? (int)$_POST['counter'] : 0;

// 2 - When you handle your form (if it is posted) : add entry to variable, then update it in session
if (!empty($_POST['submit']))   {
    // 2.1 - do needed traitments relative to form
    if(!empty($_POST['paidflag'])) {
        $paidflag = tes_input($_POST['paidflag']);  
    }
    else {
        $paidflagErr = "Pleas select either Paid or Guest Pass";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['gname'])) {
        $gname = filter_var($_POST['gname'], FILTER_SANITAZE_STRING)
    }
    else {
         $gnameErr = "<b>Error: Enter a guest name before hitting 'Submit.'</b><br>";
    }
    //...
    // Don't forget to set $new_guest var
    $new_guest = $gname . ', ' . $paidflag;

    // 2.2 - Update $guests_list and session.
    $guests_list[] = $new_guest;
    $_SESSION['guests_list'] = $guests_list;
}
?>
```

To display all existing values in $gname variable, you just need to loop on it
for exemple:

```
<p>Existing names:</p>
<ul>
<?php
for($guests_list as $entity) {
    echo '<li>' . $entity . '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

**Some tips to improve you code:**

The server will:
1 - execute PHP code
2 - Then generate and return HTML

So put all you PHP code in the same place (before you html code for example) rather than mixing it (except for the print/echo parts of course).

By default a form with an empty action post on the exact same url it is displayed so non need to use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] here.

php empty() function already return true if var doesn't exist so you don"t need to check `isset() && !empty()`

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I follow but I'm new enough to php that I'm not sure I see how to pull things in on my form.

Comment: Ok, and I didn't realize that I couldn't hit return in this box.   Do I change my form input field to $new_guest?  As in:  <b> Name:</b>  <input type="text" name="gname">

Comment: This looks like we're saving $gname, (here: $_SESSION['gname'] = $gname;) but how are we getting data into 'new_guest' and how are we preserving guest_list[] between form submits?

Comment: Sorry I first thought you use $gname to store guest list then realize my mistake.
I update my message before posting it but obviously I mess it up.
I will edit my response to be more understandable.

Comment: Ok, that's very useful. Thanks much. I wasn't able to follow everything but I got things to work. I'm going to explain a bit more, and ask another question, below.